# Cannot deploy java Web Application to Tomcat in Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, deployment

I am going to write several simple web apps, but I have an issue with deploying applications. I use `NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)` with `Apache Tomcat 8.0.3` (that came along with Netbeans).
After I click 'deploy' on my web app, there is a new *WebApplication1 run-deploy* window. It contains:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\chechulin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1 -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\chechulin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication1 -DforceRedeploy=true -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dnb.internal.action.name=redeploy run-deploy
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
```

And there is a never-ending 'Deploying WebApplication1" process. Server shows that there is no apps. And I cannot expand `Web Applications` node that should be like on the following picture:
[image: web apps tomcat]

But when I take .war file from the project /dist directory and manually deploy in to the server, it works fine!
I just cannot figure where is the problem!

Comment: Looks like you might are deploying to a different server than you think. You say you're using Tomcat 8.0.3, but the image says that you've got Tomcat 6 configured within NetBeans.  Which is your app configured to deploy to?

Comment: I just took the image from the web to show what I mean by 'web applications node'. It doesn't expand in my case.

Comment: Have you tried removing (unregistering tomcat) from within NetBeans and then registering it again?

Comment: Yes, I did (saw the same advice in another topic). But nothing has changed. Moreover, there is a server log in Netbeans, and it shows when I deploy and undeploy my .war file.

Comment: Have you tried with a basic IDE generated project.  Does that work?  Are you getting any errors in the NetBeans or Tomcat log files?  When you added Tomcat into NetBeans, did you specify a username/password to connect with and tell NetBeans to create that user?

Comment: My project is a basic IDE generated project. I created a tomcat/tomcat user. I has looked through the server log, there are `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]` and ` java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind` errors. Gonna go check what do they mean.

Comment: That means that Tomcat hasn't started properly because something else is running on the same port(s) that Tomcat uses.  Do you have multiple instances of Tomcat running?  You can check what is using port 8009 using the netstat command from a command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

Open **tomcat_users.xml** as administrator, you can find it under **conf** folder like in my case **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\tomcat_users.xml** and find tag `<user>` and add role **manager-script** in roles attribute like this

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script" />
```

But make sure tomcat is not running.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error. It seems that Netbeans can not deploy to Tomcat7 and Tomcat8 (Or at least i could not find the way how to do it). Netbeans log files gives below error

INFO [org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.deploy.TomcatManagerImpl]: TomcatManagerImpl connecting to: http://localhost:8080/manager/list
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/manager/list

Similarly it tries to use manager/deploy for deploying.

Tomcat documentation states that after tomcat7 they changed the structure and these two links are not available anymore.

When I installed Tomcat6 and configured at Netbeans, it worked and deployed as expected.